# How to get the RootViewController from a UITabBarItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

Im not even sure if the title is correct but i do not understand how else to explain it so here it goes. I will show you in steps what i do so you will understand.

First off , i am using UITabBarController where i got three different items.

1) The app starts and it shows me the first Item which is a UITableView

2) I click on a cell and it pushes me to a detailed view of the cell.

3) I navigate from there to another TabBarItem

4) I navigate back to the first TabBarItem and it still shows me the view from step 3). I DONT want that i want it to show me the first view from step 1)

How can i achieve this?

Comment: So your tab bar controller loads a UITableView as it's first tab. You click on a cell in the tableview which takes you to a detail view. Then you click on another tab. Then when you click on the first tab you want the initial tableview to show instead of the detail view?

Comment: Exactly that is correct, @ToddGower

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement `UITabBarController` delegate method:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController
 didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

Which will let you know when a tab is selected.

You can then access the `UIViewController`s of your `UITabBar` using if you don't have a reference to the `UIViewController`s:

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSArray *viewControllers
```

From that grab the refence to the appropriate `UIViewController` (or `UITableViewController`) that you want to reset and call:

```
- (NSArray *)popToRootViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

On it's `UINavigationController`. Or create a public method for that call as call `popToRootViewController` that way.

**EDIT:**

Your AppDelegate should look like this:

```
@interface AppDelegate () <UITabBarControllerDelegate>
@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    tabBarController.delegate = self;

    return YES;
}

- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController
 didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    NSLog(@"was selecated");
}
```

Comment: i implemented the UITabBarDelegate method and wrote NSLog@"test", Every time i click on a TabBarItem nothing appears?

Comment: Did you connect the delegate outlet from IB to your `AppDelegate`?

Comment: Is there any tutorial to what you wrote in your solution? Cause i have no clue what you are talking about. whenever i have used delegate methods i put delegate to self. Never connected anything to AppDelegate before

Comment: Did you create you `UITabBarController` programmatically or through IB?

Comment: I did it using StoryBoard not IB or programatically?

Comment: @TimoCengiz I've updated my answer. Copy those parts of code into your `AppDelegate` and you should be good.

Comment: Ok now it works. But how would i implement my first question to this?

Comment: I'm not going to spoon feed you all of it. I've given you all of the data required and between my post and Chase's post you have all the code to answer you question.

Comment: Lol sorry i missed that part, It works now thank you

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you've set up your tab bar controller in the your AppDelegate, you want to make it your `<UITabBarControllerDelegate>`

And in your AppDelegate.m you want to implement this method like this:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
        [(UINavigationController*)viewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```